# Input type checkbox with MVC razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, checkbox, viewmodel, form-submit

Why is the value of my checkbox not passed to my ViewModel?

My View (I omitted input tags not relevant for this post):

```
@model Pro.WebUI.ViewModels.UserViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("ManageUsers", "Administration", FormMethod.Post, 
new { id = "request-form", @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{
 <div class="form-group">
  <label for="inputAuthorize" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Authorize</label>
   <div class="col-lg-8">
     <input type="checkbox" id="Authorized" name="Authorized" value="@Model.Authorized" />
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2">
   <br /><br />
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit Request</button>
   </div>
 </div>
 }
```

My ViewModel:

```
public class UserViewModel
{
    [Key]
    public string UserID { get; private set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public bool Authorized { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Notes { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult ManageUsers(UserViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            ProcurementUser obj = new ProcurementUser();
            obj.UserName = model.Email;
            obj.FirstName = model.FirstName;
            obj.LastName = model.LastName;
            obj.Email = model.Email;
            obj.Phone = model.Phone;
            obj.Authorized = model.Authorized;
            UserRepository.SaveUser(obj);
            //success message
        }
        return View(model);
    }
```

I did not include all input tags but when I step through the code without the checkbox, all values are passed.  I looked at other checkbox questions on SOF but they mostly use the @Html.Checkbox or @Html.CheckboxFor.  I would like to just use input type="checkbox"

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes do not post back. There is a very good reason to strongly typed helpers to generate your html - they do it correctly!

Comment: Html.Checkbox or Html.CheckboxFor create a checkbox input... but generates all the code needed to do it (IDs generates as it must be, and also a Hidden with the same name to handle unchecked boxes).

Comment: I suggest also that you check the actual html generated (in particular the `value` attribute for both the `true` and `false` cases) and it should become clear. And whats the point of `<label for="inputAuthorize" ...>` - your checkbox has `name="Authorized"`, not `name="inputAuthorize"`! Always use the strongly typed html helpers!

Comment: @StephenMuecke, good info, thanks.  The label is just part of the bootstrap template.

Comment: @Romias more good info, I didn't know about the Hidden.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As has been hinted at in the comments the issue you're having is that you're not really creating your checkbox correctly:

Assuming your model has `Authorized = true` your mark-up would be:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Authorized" name="Authorized" value="true" />
```

Similarly the `false` state would result in:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Authorized" name="Authorized" value="false" />
```

But these aren't "checked" checkboxes - they're still "unchecked", and need the `checked` attribute setting:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Authorized" name="Authorized" value="true" checked />
```

As Stephen points out - an unchecked checkbox will not send any data back to the server so that you don't get confused about which options where selected.

Finally, as has also been noted, your `<label>` element is for an non-existent field looking for `inputAuthorize` instead of `Authorized`.

All of these issues would be taken care of for you if you were to use the `@Html.CheckboxFor` and `@Html.LabelFor` helper classes.

Comment: Thank you for all the good info.   I will implement the @Html.Checkboxfor.

Answer (score 11):

If we need to use `<input>` filed instead of `@Html.CheckboxFor`, we can use `"checked=\"checked\""` syntax as in this code:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="Authorized" name="Authorized" value="true" @(Model.Authorized ? "checked=\"checked\"" : "") />
```

Comment: Interesting.  How did you ever figure that out?!

Comment: @JoshYates1980, Actually I found it while following this [asp.net tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/updating-related-data-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application).  Look down at the bottom of the tutorial.